# Issue with creating variables on the go in a class in python

Tags: python, class, variables

I have a code which creates a class called 'frame'. When you call it, you define a set of arbitrary coordinates and it will create the necessary amount of self.x'n' and self.y'n' variables where 'n' is the number of coordinates you have input. Here is the code so far:

```
    class NoCoords(Exception): "raised if no coordinates are input"

    class frame:

        def __init__(self,*coords):
            try:
                for count,pos in enumerate(coords,1):
                    exec('self.x%s,self.y%s=%s'%(count,count,pos))
            except(IndexError): raise NoCoords()
```

The issue I'm having is that if I define frame1 as a frame class with 2 coordinates and then frame2 as a frame class with 3 coordinates, it won't create a separate amount of x and y coordinates for frame2. It will simply create the x1,y1 and x2,y2 variables required for frame1, and when frame2 is created it will only create the x1,y1 and x2,y2 variables, it won't create a third set of variables (x3,y3) to contain the 3rd coordinate designated in frame2.

So this brings about a few questions:
 1. What could be done (if anything) to fix this?
 2. Is this a stupid way of going about doing this?
 3. If the answer to 2 is 'yes' then what is a better way of doing what I want to accomplish?

Comment: How are you defining `frame1` and `frame2`?  Using this code, you can't actually define "a frame class with 2 coordinates"; you can only define *instances* of `frame` which each have their own number of coordinates.

Comment: frame1=frame((30,20),(50,80)),  
frame2=frame((70,35),(22,60),(90,100))

Comment: I can access `frame2.x3` and `frame2.y3` just fine.  What makes you think they're not being created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    def __init__(self,*coords):
        self.coords = {}
        for count,pos in enumerate(coords,1):
            self.coords["x%s" % count] = pos
            self.coords["y%s" % count] = pos
```

Dynamically creating variables in that manor is frowned upon. Its far nicer to just store these "variables" in a dict.

Rather than doing

```
something.x1
```

You can do

```
something.coords["x1"]
```

An alternative as pointed out would be to use

```
for count,pos in enumerate(coords,1):
    setattr(self, "x%s" % count, pos)
```

But to me, that just feels a touch dirty, it makes it harder to get the total number of "x" variables for a start.

Comment: Or even, if OP really wants that API, `setattr(self, "x%s" % count, pos)`